# How can i integrate Radzen listbox component for blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am working on a Blazor web assembly app where I am using the Radzen components. Specifically, I am using the listbox component and I am running into an issue where I am unable to bind the Data to a list of floats.

I am following an example as stated here 
https://github.com/akorchev/blazor.radzen.com/blob/master/Pages/ListBoxPage.razor

```
<RadzenListBox AllowFiltering="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" @bind-value="multipleValues" Multiple="true" Data="@Tags" TextProperty="tagName" ValueProperty="tagId" Style="margin-bottom: 20px; height:200px;" />
```

> The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute
>   'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or
>   'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like
>   'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although documentation never specifies it, the issue is caused by not using Radzen.Blazor...

```
@using Radzen.Blazor;
```

Comment: First off,  the documentation did specify it very clearly:  "Open the _Imports.razor file of your Blazor application and add this line @using Radzen.Blazor". Secondly, the issue is caused by setting: @bind-value="multipleValues" instead of @bind-Value="@multipleValues", exactly as I describe in my answer, and not because you did not import the Radzen.Blazor. And even after you import this namespace, the issue would still persist until you change -value to -Value

Comment: @enet that is your opinion, and I dont agree with you. Official github is a part of documentation and value vs Value is not even an issue, only alternatives used to overcome the main problem.